# VBA Webscraping, taking data from a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web

I have been building a scraper, I've managed to scrape most of my needed info into an excel sheet, one piece of info has been causing me problems because it's in a piece of HTML I am unfamiliar with scraping.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mapOptions = {
        property: {
            PropertyID: 1234567,
            Address: "Address, Address, Address",
            Price: "€100,000",
            Map: {"Latitude":00.0000000,"Longitude":00.0000000,"Accuracy":2,"IsAutoGeocoded":true,"Polygons":[]},
            MainPhotoUrl: "//photo.jpg",
            PropertySection: 1
        },
        propertySection: "residential",
        baseUrl: "",
        useOpenLayer: false,
        zoom: 15
    };
</script>
```

I am trying to scrape out the latitude and longitude from this script, any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it's probably not the cleanest way to do it but it should work, and you will only need to convert it to a numeric value for later use :

```
Sub tez()
Dim Src As String
Src = "___________Latitude_:03.0000080,_Longitude_:05.0000070,_"

Dim LatD As String
Dim LonD As String

LatD = GetInfo(Src, "Latitude")
LonD = GetInfo(Src, "Longitude")

MsgBox LatD & Chr(13) & LonD
End Sub

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal Str_D As String, ByVal Info_To_Get As String) As String
Dim AddressInfo As Double
AddressInfo = InStr(1, Str_D, Info_To_Get) + Len(Info_To_Get) + 2

GetInfo = Mid(Str_D, AddressInfo, InStr(AddressInfo, Str_D, ",") - AddressInfo)

End Function
```